# discord.py sorting json and making rank

Tags: python, json, sorting, discord.py, rank

```
{
"360782765890863114": {
    "money": 100000000000233425,
    "afk": 0
},
"364379179405410304": {
    "money": -999999999999957884,
    "afk": 0
},
"533112978195742721": {
    "money": 0,
    "afk": 0
}
```

I have a JSON file like this. I am trying to sort this file and make a rank command out of it.
This is my whole code

```
import discord
import asyncio  
import json
import operator
import sys

from discord.ext import commands


class money:
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.bot.loop.create_task(self.save_users())

        with open(r"/Users/gim-eunjeong/Documents/빠끔봇/cogs/users.json", 'r') as f:
            self.users = json.load(f)

    async def save_users(self):
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready()
        while not self.bot.is_closed():
            with open(r"/Users/gim-eunjeong/Documents/빠끔봇/cogs/users.json", 'w') as f:
                json.dump(self.users, f, indent=4)

            await asyncio.sleep(5)
    lines = []
    def extract_money(self ,json):
        try:
        # Also convert to int since update_time will be string.  When comparing
        # strings, "10" is smaller than "2".
            return int(['member_id']['money'])
        except KeyError:
            return 0
    lines.sort(key=extract_money, reverse=True)




    @commands.command()
    async def 돈추가(self, ctx, member:discord.Member = None):
        member = ctx.author if not member else member
        member_id = str(member.id)
        if ctx.author.id == 360782765890863114:
            await ctx.send('얼마를 줄거야?')
            def money_check(m):
                return m.content.isdigit()
            money_check = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=money_check)
            self.users[member_id]['money'] += int(money_check.content)
            embed = discord.Embed(color=member.color, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)

            embed.set_author(name=f"money = {member}", icon_url=self.bot.user.avatar_url)

            embed.add_field(name="준 돈", value=int(money_check.content))
            embed.add_field(name="총 돈", value=self.users[member_id]['money'])
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            embed=discord.Embed(title="⚠ 주의", description="빠봇 오너만 사용 가능한 명령어입니다.",color=0xd8ef56)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)


    @commands.command()
    async def 돈제외(self, ctx, member:discord.Member = None):
        member = ctx.author if not member else member
        member_id = str(member.id)
        if ctx.author.id == 360782765890863114:
            await ctx.send('얼마를 뺄거야?')
            def money_check(m):
                return m.content.isdigit()
            money_check = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=money_check)
            self.users[member_id]['money'] -= int(money_check.content)
            embed = discord.Embed(color=member.color, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)

            embed.set_author(name=f"money = {member}", icon_url=self.bot.user.avatar_url)

            embed.add_field(name="뺀 돈", value=int(money_check.content))
            embed.add_field(name="총 돈", value=self.users[member_id]['money'])
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            embed=discord.Embed(title="⚠ 주의", description="빠봇 오너만 사용 가능한 명령어입니다.",color=0xd8ef56)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)



    @commands.command()
    async def 돈지갑(self, ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
        member = ctx.author if not member else member
        member_id = str(member.id)
        if not member_id in self.users:
            await ctx.send("")
        else:
            embed = discord.Embed(color=member.color, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)

            embed.set_author(name=f"돈 = {member}", icon_url=self.bot.user.avatar_url)

            embed.add_field(name="돈", value=self.users[member_id]['money'])
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)



    async def on_message(self, message):
    # we do not want the bot to reply to itself

        author_id = str(message.author.id)        

        if not author_id in self.users:
            self.users[author_id] = {}
            self.users[author_id]['money'] = 0
            self.users[author_id]['afk'] = 0

        if message.content.startswith('빠봇 돈줘'):
            getmoney = random.randint(1, 10000)
            await message.channel.send('{}원을 받았다고.'.format(getmoney))
            self.users[author_id]['money'] += getmoney                       




        if message.content.startswith('빠봇 숫자게임'):
            await message.channel.send('얼마를 걸거야?')
            def money_check(m):
                return m.content.isdigit()
            money_check = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=money_check)
            if int(money_check.content) > self.users[author_id]['money']:
                await message.channel.send('현재 돈보다 많은 양을 걸었어')
            elif int(money_check.content) < self.users[author_id]['money']:
                self.users[author_id]['money'] -= int(money_check.content)

                await message.channel.send('1~10 사이의 숫자를 맞춰봐')

                def guess_check(m):
                    return m.content.isdigit()

                guess = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=guess_check)
                answer = random.randint(1, 10)
                print(answer)
                if guess is None:
                    fmt = '너무 오래걸린다.. 걍 내가 말해야지 {}.'
                    await message.channel.send(fmt.format(answer))
                    return
                if int(guess.content) == answer:
                    await message.channel.send('정답! 건 돈의 10배가 돌아왔다!')
                    self.users[author_id]['money'] += int(money_check.content)*10
                else:
                    await message.channel.send('미안하지만 정답은 {}(이)라구.'.format(answer))

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(money(bot))
```

```
￼
￼
```

**Money rank (embed) Top 10 users**

1

@맥꾸 / 1437000￦

2

<@429549533731487754> / 833000￦

3

@잠시 왔습니댜 곧 다시 외출합니댜 ㅌㅌ / 628000￦

4

@맹구 / 554000￦

5

@TanzenT / 512000￦

6

@한설 / 492000￦

7

@사막여우 / 409900￦

8

<@365396996774952961> / 324000￦

9

<@461073040642670592> / 268000￦

10

@{《\하이루☆/》} / 262000￦

This is the expected data

Comment: Show expected data

Comment: Can you show expected result from input json in your question?

Comment: @Alderven ohh I messed up a liiitle bit. the json example is the expected result. i want it to be like that when it's messed up

Comment: Then what is input data? Basically can you show the data on input and the data you want to have at the end.

Comment: hm... okay... then the other thing. how can I show the rank? @Alderven